# Как открыть div блок на всю страницу?

Tags: html, jquery, css

Как открыть div блок `.conteiner` на всю страницу,  как на данном сайте, под кодом до вопроса *"Развернуть фрагмент"* ?

https://jsfiddle.net/p7cc1uys/

```js
$("#button").click(function() {
  //alert("Проверка");
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
html,
body {
  min-height: 100%;
}
body {
  background: #ddd;
}
.conteiner {
  background: #F3EFE1;
  overflow: auto;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 40px;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 9px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.32);
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 9px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.32);
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 9px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.32);
}
#button {
  float: right;
  width: 80px;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 4px 13px;
  border: solid 1px #004F72;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  font: 12px Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #E5FFFF;
  background-color: #3BA4C7;
  background-image: linear-gradient(top, #3BA4C7 0%, #1982A5 100%);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #bababa, inset 0px 0px 1px #ffffff;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #bababa, inset 0px 0px 1px #ffffff;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #bababa, inset 0px 0px 1px #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="conteiner">
  <div id="button">Развернуть</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Еще один вариант

```js
$(".button").click(function() {
  var parent = $(this).parents()[0]; //получаем родительський элемент
  var width = $(parent).width(); //узнаем ширину родительського блока
  
  
  $(parent).toggleClass("full"); //добавляем/убираем класс где блок во весь екран

  if(width=='200'){ //если ширина равна 200
    $(parent).children('.button').text('Свернуть'); //если истина то надпись "Свернуть"
    }
  else {
    $(parent).children('.button').text('Развернуть');//если ложь то надпись "Свернуть"
    }
});
```

```css
/* блок во весь екран */
.full {  
  width: 100% !important;
  height: 100% !important;
  position: absolute !important;
  margin-top: 0px !important;
  z-index: 99999 !important;
  }


* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
html,
body {
  min-height: 100%;
}
body {
  background: #ddd;
}
.conteiner {
  background: #F3EFE1;
  overflow: auto;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 40px;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 9px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.32);
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 9px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.32);
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 9px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.32);
}
.button {
  float: right;
  width: 80px;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 4px 13px;
  border: solid 1px #004F72;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  font: 12px Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #E5FFFF;
  background-color: #3BA4C7;
  background-image: linear-gradient(top, #3BA4C7 0%, #1982A5 100%);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #bababa, inset 0px 0px 1px #ffffff;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #bababa, inset 0px 0px 1px #ffffff;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #bababa, inset 0px 0px 1px #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="conteiner">
  <div class="button">Развернуть</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Как сделать проверку, когда блок на весь экран, чтобы менять текст: Развернуть /  Свернуть ?

Comment: Если у вас ширина блока фиксирована то  узнаете ширину блока если она не равна 200px  то текст будет "свернуть" если равна 200px  то "развернуть". Подправил ответ.

Comment: И еще раз спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

```js
$("#button").click(function() {
  var h = $(document).height();//получаем высоту документа и записываем в переменную "h"

  $(".conteiner").css({'width': "100%", 'height': h, 'position': "absolute",'margin-top': "0px", 'z-index': "99999"}); //устанавливаем новые стили для <div class="conteiner">
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
html,
body {
  min-height: 100%;
}
body {
  background: #ddd;
}
.conteiner {
  background: #F3EFE1;
  overflow: auto;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 40px;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 9px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.32);
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 9px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.32);
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 9px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.32);
}
#button {
  float: right;
  width: 80px;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 4px 13px;
  border: solid 1px #004F72;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  font: 12px Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #E5FFFF;
  background-color: #3BA4C7;
  background-image: linear-gradient(top, #3BA4C7 0%, #1982A5 100%);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #bababa, inset 0px 0px 1px #ffffff;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #bababa, inset 0px 0px 1px #ffffff;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #bababa, inset 0px 0px 1px #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="conteiner">
  <div id="button">Развернуть</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Такой вариант я уже пробовал. Мне нужно чтобы этот блок перекрывал весь остальной контент на сайте текст, фото и так далее...

Comment: Детали нужно уточнять в вопросе. Подправил ответ.

Answer (score 1):

**Вроде бы так** добавляем класс который открывает или делает его на 
100vw + 100vh и всё

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".button").click(function() {
    $("pre").toggleClass("show");
    $(this).toggleClass("active");
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
html,
body {
  background: #ddd;
}
.wrapper {
  display: table;
  margin: auto;
}
pre {
  width: 540px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  height: 300px;
  background: #fefefe;
  overflow: hidden;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  padding-left: 10px;
  font-size: 12px;
}
p.button {
  display: inline;
  padding-top: 3px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.icon-enlarge {
  padding-right: 6px;
}
p i+i {
  position: relative;
  top: -2px;
}
.show {
  width: 100vw;
  height: auto;
  font-size: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  z-index: 100;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
.active {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 101;
}
main {
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
}
main p {
  font-size: 20px;
  width: 90%;
  text-align: justify;
  margin: auto;
}
.text {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://i.icomoon.io/public/temp/36225a5027/UntitledProject/style.css">
<main>
  <h2>Donec rutrum congue leo eget malesuada.</h2>
  <p>Vivamus magna justo, lacinia eget consectetur sed, convallis at tellus. Vivamus suscipit tortor eget felis porttitor volutpat. Proin eget tortor risus. Praesent sapien massa, convallis a pellentesque nec, egestas non nisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
    consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris blandit aliquet elit, eget tincidunt nibh pulvinar a. Curabitur non nulla sit amet nisl tempus convallis quis ac lectus. Proin eget tortor risus. Vivamus magna justo, lacinia eget consectetur sed, convallis at tellus.
    Mauris blandit aliquet elit, eget tincidunt nibh pulvinar a.</p>
</main>
<div class="wrapper">
  <code>
  <pre>
* {
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
}
html,
body {
min-height: 100%;
}
body {
background: #ddd;
}
.conteiner {
background: #F3EFE1;
overflow: auto;
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
margin: 0 auto;
margin-top: 40px;
position: relative;
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 9px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.32);
-moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 9px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.32);
box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 9px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.32);
}
#button {
float: right;
width: 80px;
cursor: pointer;
text-align: center;
padding: 4px 13px;
border: solid 1px #004F72;
-webkit-border-radius: 4px;
-moz-border-radius: 4px;
border-radius: 4px;
font: 12px Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
font-weight: bold;
color: #E5FFFF;
background-color: #3BA4C7;
background-image: linear-gradient(top, #3BA4C7 0%, #1982A5 100%);
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #bababa, inset 0px 0px 1px #ffffff;
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #bababa, inset 0px 0px 1px #ffffff;
box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #bababa, inset 0px 0px 1px #ffffff;
}
  </pre>
</code> 
  <p class="button">
    <i class="icon-enlarge"></i>
    <i class="text">открыть на весь экран</i>
  </p>
</div>
<main>
  <h2>Donec rutrum congue leo eget malesuada.</h2>
  <p>Vivamus magna justo, lacinia eget consectetur sed, convallis at tellus. Vivamus suscipit tortor eget felis porttitor volutpat. Proin eget tortor risus. Praesent sapien massa, convallis a pellentesque nec, egestas non nisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
    consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris blandit aliquet elit, eget tincidunt nibh pulvinar a. Curabitur non nulla sit amet nisl tempus convallis quis ac lectus. Proin eget tortor risus. Vivamus magna justo, lacinia eget consectetur sed, convallis at tellus.
    Mauris blandit aliquet elit, eget tincidunt nibh pulvinar a.</p>
</main>
```

ссылка на [codepen](http://codepen.io/Geyan/pen/XjmoOz)

Answer (score 1):

```js
$("#button").click(function() {
  $(this).closest('.conteiner').toggleClass('expland');
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
html,
body {
  min-height: 100%;
}
body {
  background: #ddd;
}
.conteiner {
  background: #F3EFE1;
  overflow: auto;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 40px;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 9px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.32);
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 9px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.32);
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 9px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.32);
}
.conteiner.expland {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0; 
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0;
}
#button {
  float: right;
  width: 80px;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 4px 13px;
  border: solid 1px #004F72;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  font: 12px Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #E5FFFF;
  background-color: #3BA4C7;
  background-image: linear-gradient(top, #3BA4C7 0%, #1982A5 100%);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #bababa, inset 0px 0px 1px #ffffff;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #bababa, inset 0px 0px 1px #ffffff;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #bababa, inset 0px 0px 1px #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="conteiner">
  <div id="button">Развернуть</div>
</div>
```